# How to compute "weight"?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Assume I have a list of 100 used cars, which the following information for each: year, make, model, mileage, selling price. **How could I figure out how much does the year, make, model, and mileage affect the cars selling price?**

Is there a program that'll do this? If someone can explain the math to me - or at least point me in the right direction, maybe I can write a simple program to figure this out myself.

Comment: Based on past data.

Comment: Not sure if there is anything special about the data being "past", but let's say my 100 used cars info was from last year. How do I figure out how each attribute affects the selling price?

Comment: There is definitely something special about the data being "past" in that "future" data is not available to you, and most (if not all) of statistics is based on the assumption that history repeats itself. I would start with checking what correlation exists between above-mentioned parameters and the selling price.

Comment: I did not suggest that I had future data. I did say that I "have a list of 100 used cars", so that implies that I got at some time in the past. Your suggestion for me to "start with checking what correlation exists" is my question. What you are suggesting to do is what I am trying to find out how to do.

Comment: If you're aware of R, this might be useful - https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/cor.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have considered using regression analysis?